# How to grep specific value based on matching search value

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I need help in finding `"db-unique-name"` that has `lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE"`.

```
cat db_systems.txt

     "db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "dfadfasfsadfasdfasdf",
      "lifecycle-details": null,
      "lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE",
--
      "db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "asdfsadfasdfasfd",
      "lifecycle-details": "Resource was terminated at the backend.",
      "lifecycle-state": "FAILED",
--
      "db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "lifecycle-details": "Resource was terminated at the backend.",
      "lifecycle-state": "FAILED",
    enter code here
```

Tried `"db-unique-name"` value based on `"lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE"`. the following , but it gives wrong value

```
cat db_systems.txt  |  egrep -A -6  "lifecycle-state|AVAILABLE" | grep  db-unique-name
"db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
"db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
```

I also tried this, but it is listing all of them

```
cat db_systems.txt |  awk -F";" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /AVAILABLE|db-unique-name/){print $1}}}' | grep db-unique-name
"db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
"db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
"db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
```

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: Is that the _actual_ and original file that you're working with, or have you modified the file from some JSON original? It would be _easier_ to work with a JSON document (like the output of `oci network vcn list` or similar command would be), and the format looks as if it could have been JSON from the start.

Comment: Following @Kusalananda , `jq` generally rocks at parsing json from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

Using `grep`:

```
 grep -B6 AVAILABLE file | grep db-unique-name
 "db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
```

- `B` Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.

Using `awk`:

```
 awk '{a[++i]=$0;}/AVAILABLE/{print a[NR-6];}' file
 "db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
```

Comment: perhaps worth explaining what the `-B` flag does

Comment: @SteveLorimer updated...

Answer (score 5):

You can try this with GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN { RS = "--" } /"lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE"/ {  gsub("^[[:blank:]]*", "", $1);  print $1 }' file
```

Output:

```
"db-unique-name":"p00z5bj_iad2bj"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with JSON formatted data (the fragments look like it) you should certainly have a look at `jq` which is a pretty useful tool for such data.

If your data looks like this

```
{
    "db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "dfadfasfsadfasdfasdf",
      "lifecycle-details": null,
      "lifecycle-state": "AVAILABLE"
}
{
      "db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "asdfsadfasdfasfd",
      "lifecycle-details": "Resource was terminated at the backend.",
      "lifecycle-state": "FAILED"
}
{
      "db-unique-name": "p00u5bh_iad2bj",
      "db-workload": "OLTP",
      "defined-tags": {},
      "freeform-tags": {},
      "id": "asdfasdfasdf",
      "lifecycle-details": "Resource was terminated at the backend.",
      "lifecycle-state": "FAILED"
}
```

then this `jq` statement

```
jq 'select(."lifecycle-state" == "AVAILABLE") | ."db-unique-name" ' < db_systems.txt
```

will output

```
"p00z5bj_iad2bj"
```

However, if your file actually looks like the example you've given (with `--` as separators and no {} object notation) then the `awk` solution might be easier, it's somewhat difficult to shove non-JSON data into jq...

Comment: Could you give an example showing how `jq` would produce the desired output from the example input? Without such an example, this isn't really answering the question and should probably just be a comment.

Comment: According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368275/how-to-grep-specific-string-based-on-matching-search-string#comment108564016_61368275) this is the actual data and I don't understand why the question was closed there.

Comment: Oh I did not see that, sorry. Yes, in that case jq will not fit the bill.

Comment: @Freddy The data seems to come from an Oracle Virtual Cloud Network (`vcn`) command. These commands output JSON.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$ awk '$1=="\"db-unique-name\":"{name=$2} 
       $1=="\"lifecycle-state\":" && $2 ~ /AVAILABLE/ {print name}' systems.txt 
"p00z5bj_iad2bj",
```

Or, if you want the entire `db-unique-name` line, try:

```
$ awk '$1=="\"db-unique-name\":"{name=$0} 
       $1=="\"lifecycle-state\":" && $2 ~ /AVAILABLE/ {print name}' systems.txt 
     "db-unique-name": "p00z5bj_iad2bj",
```

Answer (score 2):

With this approach of first creating an array, `f[]` below, that maps each elements name to its value you can access every field by it's name and so create complex conditions and print fields in any order:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"?,[[:space:]]*$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/".*$/,"",tag)
    sub(/.*"/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
/^--/ { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( f["lifecycle-state"] == "AVAILABLE" ) {
        print f["db-unique-name"]
    }
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
p00z5bj_iad2bj
```

For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"|"?,[[:space:]]*$/,"")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/".*$/,"",tag)
    sub(/.*"/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
/^--/ { prt() }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    recNr++
    if ( (f["lifecycle-state"] == "FAILED") || ( (f["db-unique-name"] ~ /bh/) && (f["db-workload"] == "OLTP") ) ) {
        print recNr, f["lifecycle-details"], f["id"], f["db-unique-name"]
    }
    delete f
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2,Resource was terminated at the backend.,asdfsadfasdfasfd,p00u5bh_iad2bj
3,Resource was terminated at the backend.,asdfasdfasdf,p00u5bh_iad2bj
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are extracts of JSON data, wrap them back into JSON and use a JSON tool.

```
{ echo '{'; sed 's/^ *-- *$/"": ""} {/' db_systems.txt; echo '"": ""}'; } |
jq 'select(."lifecycle-state" == "AVAILABLE") | ."db-unique-name" '
```

(`jq` query [by Hans-Martin Mosner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/581822))

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful.

```
grep -B 6 AVAILABLE db_systems.txt | grep db-unique-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the db-unique-name and lifecycle-state fields are mandatory and are always output in the same order (but not assuming that there are always exactly 5 lines in between) I'd use:

```
cat db_systems.txt \
  | grep -E '"(db-unique-name|lifecycle-state)":' \
  | grep -B 1 '"AVAILABLE"' \
  | grep db-unique-name \
  | cut -d\" -f4
```

Which is perfect for piping into `xargs`, `while read name`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
grep -e db-unique-name -e lifecycle-state.*AVAILABLE < filename | grep -B1 lifecycle-state.*AVAILABLE | grep db-unique-name
```

Unlike using `-B6`, this does not assume there are 6 line between the two lines of interest.

(Of course, many other responses rightly suggested using `jq`, which is definitely the better option).